# Django framework, working with modelforms>

Tags: django-models, django-forms

Basically, I have a model `User` (django's model) and `Customer` (Which has 1:1 with User Model)
I also have a `List` model, where a logged in customer can make a list of whatever.
The `ListForm`:

```
class CreateListForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = List
        fields = ['list_title', 'excerpt', ]
```

And The `View (POST) function`:

```
def post(self, request):
        post = request.POST

        list_form = CreateListForm(request.POST)
        if list_form.is_valid():
            list_form.save()
            return redirect('indexpage')
```

There is also a hidden input which I added in the html template that has the customer id:

```
<input type="hidden" name="customer" value="{{ user.customer.id }}">
```

However, when I try to save the form via `list_form.save()`, I get `NOT NULL constraint failed: todo_list.customer_id`.

I can pass the customer in the fields, but that would be counter logical, as only logged in users can make a list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can include hidden fields in your form which should keep all data together as part of django's forms.

```
class CreateListForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = List
        fields = ['customer', 'list_title', 'excerpt', ]
        widgets = {
            'customer': forms.HiddenInput()
        }
```

You can provide data to hidden fields when you create the form in a view;

```
form = CreateListForm(initial={'customer': request.user.customer.id})
```